# MySQL: question marks instead of symbols

Tags: mysql, sql, encoding, utf-8

I've created a database in MariaDB, then ran some SQL to create tables
like this:

```
    create table customers
    ( customerid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
      name char(50) not null,
      address char(100) not null,
      city char(30) not null
    );

    create table orders
    ( orderid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
      customerid int unsigned not null,
      amount float(6,2),
      date date not null
    );
```

Then i tried to populate it with some data:

```
insert into customers values
  (3, "Саша Валентей", "12, ул. Гудвина", "г. Изумрудный"),
  (4, "Ева Легкая", "34, пр. Незнайки", "г. Солнечный"),
  (5, "Слава Моргунов", "56, пер. Поттера", "пгт Хогвартс");

insert into orders values
  (NULL, 3, 69.98, "2008-04-02"),
  (NULL, 1, 49.99, "2008-04-15"),
  (NULL, 2, 74.98, "2008-04-19"),
  (NULL, 3, 24.99, "2008-05-01");
```

It's cyrillic, if that matters. And now i have question marks where my
chars should be. My server is UTF-8 and tha table seems to be latin_swedish_ci. How do i solve this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE customers CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: This will fix the table for further Cyrillic use, but it cannot recover the data already inserted.  (There is no fix.)

Comment: Why don't he just delete and then re-insert the data?

Comment: Yes, that is probably the thing to do.